# In R shiny, how to specify column of reactive object for plotting?

Tags: r, plot, vector, shiny

When first invoking the below MWE code, a 2-column table of default values appears in the main panel: 60 periods listed in the left column and values of 20.0% for each of the 60 periods in the right column. This works correctly and is shown in the 1st image below.

When the user clicks on the "Vector plots" action button in the main panel, a plot should appear showing those same values of 0.2 for 60 periods. Instead, as shown in the 2nd image below, I get a plot of the values of 1-60 (from 1st column of the table) and then values of 20 for periods 61-120. This is incorrect.

The object, generated in the below MWE, common to both the table and the plot is `vectorsAll`.

How do I specify the correct column (2nd column) of `vectorsAll` to plot? It currently plots the first column (1-60) and I don't know why it runs out to 120.

I'm trying to do this in native Shiny, no other plot packages like ggplot.

In operating this App, if the user clicks on the "Input Liabilities" action button in the sidebar panel, an input matrix grid appears in modal dialog. Only the 1st row "A" is operational in this MWE. If the user changes the value in R, it is instantly reflected in the main panel table (works correctly) and plot.

I stripped down this code enough so the shinyWidgets package isn't required --- I think.

Note that the line below `output$graph1 <-renderPlot(plot(sapply`... strips out the % sign from the `vectorsAll` object.

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyMatrix)

matrix1Input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE),
              cols = list(extend=FALSE,names=FALSE,editableNames=FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

pct <- function(x){paste(format(round(x*100,digits=1),nsmall=1),"%",sep="")} # convert to percentage

vectorBase <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model..."),
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")),align="center",
                        style="margin-top:-15px;margin-bottom:5px")),
      # Panels rendered with uiOuput & renderUI in server to stop flashing at invocation
      uiOutput("Panels") 
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(
                   actionButton('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values'),
                   actionButton('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots'),
                 ), # close fluid row
                 
                 div(style = "margin-top: 5px"),
                 
                 # Shows outputs on each page of main panel   
                 uiOutput('showResults')), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  base_input  <- reactive(input$base_input)
  showResults <- reactiveValues()
  yield       <- function(){vectorBase(60,input$base_input[1,1])} # Must remain in server section
  
  # --- Conditional panels rendered here rather than in UI to eliminate invocation flashing ------------>
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==4",
        actionButton('showLiabilityGrid','Input Liabilities',style='width:100%;background-color:LightGrey'),
        setShadow(id='showLiabilityGrid'),
        div(style = "margin-bottom: 10px"),
      ), # close conditional panel
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==3"),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4")
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  # --- Below defines the vectorsAll object before user clicks on actionButton "Input Liabilities" ---->
  vectorsAll <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$showLiabilityGrid)){df <- NULL}
    else {
      if(input$showLiabilityGrid < 1){df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(0.2))}  # define what you want to display by default
      else {
        req(input$base_input)
        df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(yield()[,2]))
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    df
  }) # close reactive
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({vectorsAll()})
  
  # --- Below produces vector values after clicking "Vector Values" button; see above for pre-click ---->
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,{showResults$showme<-tagList(tableOutput("table1"))},ignoreNULL=FALSE)
  
  # --- Below produces vector plots -------------------------------------------------------------------->   
  output$graph1 <-renderPlot(plot(sapply(vectorsAll(),function(x)gsub("%","",x)))) 
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{showResults$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")})
  
  # --- Below sends both vector plots and vector values to UI section above ---------------------------->
  output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})
  
  # --- Below for modal dialog inputs ------------------------------------------------------------------>
  observeEvent(input$showLiabilityGrid,
               {showModal(modalDialog(matrix1Input("base_input"),div(style = "margin-top: 0px"),useShinyjs(),
  ))}) # close modalDialog, showModal, showModal function, and observeEvent, in that order
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will resolve it.

```
 output$graph1 <-renderPlot(plot(vectorsAll()[,1],sapply(vectorsAll()[,2], function(x)gsub("%", "", x)) ))
```

[image: output]

Comment: That works great, thanks. I was trying vectorsAll([,2]), but now I see the row/column locator in [ ] needs to follow the ( ) and not reside inside the ( ). So correct syntax is object( )[r,c]. By repeating this way maybe I'll finally remember. I took a 2 week vacation and seemed to forget a lot during that time.